# PHP: Key Changes from Array to String

Tags: php, arrays, facebook, foreach, facebook-php-sdk

I am fairly new to PHP and am using it with the Facebook PHP SDK. Below, I am trying to get the 'name' fields of 'admin_creator' from the Facebook Graph API however the key changes from arrays to strings.

```
foreach($getAdminCreator as $key){
    //var_export($key);
    if(isset($key['admin_creator'])){
        //var_export($key);
        //var_export($key['admin_creator']);
        foreach ($key['admin_creator'] as $key){
            //var_export($key);
            //echo $key['name'] . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

The entire thing works and `var_export(key)` would return an array up until the last foreach loop. Before entering the last foreach loop, `var_export($key['admin_creator']);` would return an array like this:

```
array ( 'name' => 'NAME', 'id' => 'ID', )array ( 'name' => 'NAME', 'id' => 'ID', )
```

However, inside the foreach loop when I'm trying to retrieve the values of 'name', `var_export($key);` returns strings:

```
'NAME''ID''NAME''ID'
```

and using `echo $key['name'] . '<br>';` would just print the first characters and give Illegal string offset warnings.

Since I am new to PHP I would like to know if there's a way to fix this and get the values of 'name'. Since it returns as strings I am unable to export the values of the 'name' field.

*Note that 'name' and 'id' refer to the fields while NAME and ID are replacement values for the values of 'name' and 'id'.

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you are trying to do in my earlier answer. If `$key['admin_creator']` is just a list with a `name` and an `id`, you shouldn't need to iterate over it with `foreach`. Just do `if (isset($key['admin_creator'])) { echo $key['admin_creator']['name'] . '<br>'; }`

Comment: @MattRaines It works now! Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I've written it down as an answer so you can accept it if you like, to mark the question resolved and grant us both a little reputation on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP arrays can be numerically indexed, and behave like traditional arrays from other languages, or they can have string indexes and behave more like lists. You can still iterate over a list with `foreach`, so your inner loop first sets `$key` to the string 'NAME', then the string 'ID'.

To access the `name` property of the list directly, you can just use `$key['admin_creator']['name']`. In your example you can replace your inner loop with

```
if (isset($key['admin_creator'])) {
    echo $key['admin_creator']['name'] . '<br>';
}
```